# Size of the line parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

Is there any parameter that will read whole line from the input? I know there is getline(buffer, size_of_the_line) function, but I don't want to limit a size_of_the_line property to just the number I define, but limitless. Is there such a thing at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a free function defined in `<string>` header:

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line_of_input;
    std::getline(std::cin, line_of_input); // limited only by the max size of string
}
```

Comment: Nice! For being first to reply, I will give to this answer status of the accepted one.

Comment: I wasn't first, to be honest :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), it will read a full line into a `std::string`:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for. :)